# jquery lightbox automatic website scrolling when next button hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need help with the following question:

So I want to place text in jquery using one of the following (open for suggestions):
http://fancybox.net/home
http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html
http:// jacklmoore. kom/colorbox/example1/

But what I want to do is:
if the next button is pressed the website should smoothly scroll to a predefined location:

something along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function filterPath(string) {
return string
.replace(/^\//,'')
.replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
.replace(/\/$/,'');
}
var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

$('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
if (  locationPath == thisPath
&& (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
&& this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
  var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
  if (target) {
    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
    $(this).click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
        location.hash = target;
      });
    });
  }
}
});

// use the first element that is "scrollable"
function scrollableElement(els) {
for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
  var el = arguments[i],
      $scrollElement = $(el);
  if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
    return el;
  } else {
    $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
    var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
    $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
    if (isScrollable) {
      return el;
    }
  }
 }
return [];
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

--> scoling

http://fancybox.net/api